# Tools to highlight deprecated functions in PHP4 sources?

Tags: php, deprecated

Is there any magic tools i can use to scan source code that was written for PHP4 to highlight deprecated functions in PHP5? I'm currently running the latest version of PHP on a server and need to port this code. Is there anything out there that can give me a hand?

Comment: A list of deprecated functions won't be sufficient.  Some functions that used to accept certain arguments now throw an error if the arguments received aren't of the expected type.  IIRC, array_merge() is one example -- it used to accept a NULL argument; now it throws an error if any argument isn't an array.  Long story short, the only real way to be sure migration from PHP 4 to 5 is complete is to test heavily.

Comment: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated too. It's a nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP 5.3 will throw an [`E_DEPRECATED`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) warning if you set your error reporting levels to show them.

Comment: The thing is i can fix the errors when each occurs but i was looking for a way to scan all sources. I'm currently fixing these errors but i might miss some that might not appear when im testing the software.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something like this myself.  Using this list of [deprecated features in PHP 5.3.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php), I made a regex to search for any use of these functions:

```
(?i:(call_user_method\(|call_user_method_array\(|define_syslog_variables\(|dl\(|ereg\(|ereg_replace\(|eregi\(|eregi_replace\(|set_magic_quotes_runtime\(|session_register\(|session_unregister\(|session_is_registered\(|set_socket_blocking\(|split\(|spliti\(|sql_regcase\(|mysql_db_query\(|mysql_escape_string\())
```

*(Case insensitive, with each function name including the opening parenthesis just to avoid false positives; "dl" would bring up lots of noise otherwise.)*

If you're on a system with `find` and `grep`, you could then just execute something like this:

```
find <directory to search> -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -R -P -H "<above regex>" {} \;
```

Just to make a more concrete example, I just used the following:

```
find htdocs -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -R -P -H "(?i:(call_user_method\(|call_user_method_array\(|define_syslog_variables\(|dl\(|ereg\(|ereg_replace\(|eregi\(|eregi_replace\(|set_magic_quotes_runtime\(|session_register\(|session_unregister\(|session_is_registered\(|set_socket_blocking\(|split\(|spliti\(|sql_regcase\(|mysql_db_query\(|mysql_escape_string\())" {} \;
```

Looks like I now need to replace a few instances of `session_register` and `session_unregister` myself!

The same sort of thing could be done for deprecated INI directives and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The [appendices of the manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php) contain some migration information but I don't think it contains what you're looking for.

One way (which might be inaccurate but could be used) I thought of was the news.txt included in each PHP download. I'm [writing a script](https://github.com/rmasters/php-news) atm that parses this file and checking for deprecated functions could be something I could add. I am working on another project atm but I'd like to add functionality for this in the larger rebuilt version.

Comment: The link to your script is broken. Can you fix this please?

Comment: Updated, will make it a single file I think.